# Calling a method in android during onload event

Tags: android, android-activity, onload-event

`onCreate()` does not get called when I leave the application using back button and start it immediately. I believe this is because, Android has not killed the application process yet. I tried using @AfterViews, the same happens. How could I make sure that every time the application is started, my specific code runs?

Does not get called when I leave the application using back button and then start.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        methodToRun();
    }
```

I use this `onBackPressed()` to exit the application.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        this.moveTaskToBack(true);
        this.finish();
    }
```

Even @AfterViews does not get called when I leave the application using back button and then start.

```
@AfterViews
    void checkAgreementFlag(){
        methodToRun();
    }
```

I want methodToRun() to always get called. How would I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Call methodToRun() from onResume()  of activity.

[onResume():](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29) Called when the activity will start interacting with the user. At this point your activity is at the top of the activity stack, with user input going to it.

onCreate(): is called when your application is starting first time.

onRestart(): Called after your activity has been stopped, prior to it being started again.

onStart(): Called when the activity is becoming visible to the user.

onStop() : When the activity is no longer visible.

For the back key scenario activity lifecycle:

```
onCreate()->onStart()->onResume()->Activity running
```

After pressing back key

```
onPause()->onStop()
```

If the activity is coming back then

```
onRestart()->onStart()->onResume()->Activity running
```

otherwise `onDestroy()` will be called.